# Derivable function on an interval $ [a,b]$ with derivative unbounded on $[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis

> I'm searching for a derivable function defined on an interval $ [a,b]$ whose derivative is not bounded on $[a,b]$.

Comment: What ideas have you had? What are your thoughts?

Comment: I wanted to take as derivative 1/x if x>0 and for example 0 if x=0. But I think it doesn't work.

Comment: Hint: functions with unbounded derivatives usually have a pretty darn steep slope at some point of the function.

Comment: Yes, I was searching for something like that, but I don't find an example. The problem is that it has to be defined on whole the interval [a,b].

Comment: Do you mean the derivative must be defined? Or the function?

Comment: The derivative.

Comment: Note: if the derivative is continuous on the closed interval it attains its bounds and cannot be unbounded.

Comment: Hint: Start from a sinusoid on [0,1], tamper with the horizontal axis to have infinitely many archs and with the vertical axis to make this possible while having a limit at 1. Finally, make the "sinusoid" raise more and more vertically in each arch, when one goes closer and closer to 1.

Comment: @MarkBennet: The correct deduction from your comment is that the derivative is not continuous, not that it must be bounded.

Comment: @TonyK That was what I intended OP to deduce.

Answer (score 1):

A classic example is $x^2 \sin(1/x^2)$ for $x \in (0,1]$ and $0$ for $x=0$

Comment: Ok Thanks, but how do you know that this function is derivable in 0? It's quite difficult to check it with the definition I think, no?

Comment: @jens While its derivative at zero may not be a result of the usual cookbook shortcuts, the limit definition of the derivative that I'm accustomed to works just fine. What are you using? You can use the fact that $| \sin(x) | \le 1$.

Comment: Yes, ok, I was too fast with answering, It is indeed quite easy:).

Comment: But I still struggle with my intuition, because this function his derivitave goes to infinity (because the function is not bounded) if we come closer to zero, but also he is zero at x=0? Can you explain it?

Comment: First, notice any function you squeeze between $x^2$ and $-x^2$ will have a derivative of zero at zero. Graphing them might help you see that you can "zig zag" from between them with as steep a slope as you want, and as close to zero as you want. $\sin(1/x^2)$ does that kind of zig zagging, so the slope (derivative) swings from increasingly negative values to increasingly positive values and so on as $x$ heads towards zero.

Comment: Ok thanks, I think I understand it.